# TeX Syntax In Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Why cant I write Tex syntax directly in Mathematica however, I can paste it in from another editor and it is converted to pretty syntax?

Comment: Did you mean 'TeX' instead of 'Lex'?  They are quite different!  Moreover, this seems more a question about Mathematica than about TeX.  This site is focussed primarily on stuff that will be processed with the tex program rather than TeX-like things in other programs.

Comment: For questions about Mathematica, please consider using the [Stack Exchange website on Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GeneratingAndImportingTeX.html

ToExpression["input",TeXForm] converts TeX input to Mathematica